# RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_WRITE) on newly created user

Tags: c, winapi, windows-authentication, windows-security, windows-process

After i successfully create a new user, add user to built-in admins group, i would like to edit the newly created user's registry (this program is an elevated-as-admin program). I called `NetUserAdd()`, `NetLocalGroupAddMembers()`, `LogonUser()`, and then, finally `LoadUserProfile()` so the user's directory exists.

Excuse the sloppy code, but this is what I am doing after that:

```
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken,TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,&sa,SecurityImpersonation,TokenPrimary,&hNewToken);
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hNewToken);

HKEY hKey;
LSTATUS stat = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE, &hKey);
// stat is 5 (ACCESS_DENIED) when KEY_WRITE is added, it
// returns 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS) when it's just KEY_READ

RegCloseKey(hKey);
RevertToSelf();

CloseHandle(hNewToken);
```

The error is on the `RegOpenCurrentUser()` line. It errors out when I ask to write to that user's HKU registry. It works perfectly fine if I use just `KEY_READ`

Is this even possible what I am trying to do? Is the user's registry hive even created yet? Or does the user have to physically sign on to create it?

Ultimately what i would want to do is create GPO's for the new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the user profile loaded with `LoadUserProfile()`, you don't really need to use `RegOpenCurrentUser()` at all.  You can instead use the `hProfile` field of the [`PROFILEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773378.aspx) that `LoadUserProfile()` returns:

> hProfile
>   Type: HANDLE
>
> A handle to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry subtree.
>
> ...
>
> When the LoadUserProfile call returns successfully, the hProfile member receives a registry key handle opened to the root of the user's subtree, opened with full access (KEY_ALL_ACCESS).

Comment: Thank you so much! You made everything so much easier and straight forward.